# css - Numbers vertically in line css

Tags: css

By using a different font, the numbers are not in line vertically.
How do you solve this problem?

I couldn't find a solution by searching google or stackoverflow.
Anyone have a simple solution for this ?

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/egbmkxL0/3/)

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans);
```

Comment: Use a mono-spaced font if you want that precision...or use a different layout method  http://jsfiddle.net/egbmkxL0/4/

Comment: Each font has its own "drawing". The one you chose had numbers with different sizes. As @Paulie_D mentioned, you can use other font family that meets your needs.

Comment: Raleway font - represents number that way only..! you cannot change that, find another font for nuimbers